# How to represent a Liouville projection superoperator in Hilbert space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics, quantum-information, hilbert-space, density-operator

Is there a general way to represent a Liouville projection operator in Hilbert space, or can they take on any form so long as they satisfy the required properties of a projector?

e.g. The thermal projection superoperator is represented in Hilbert space as:

$$ \mathcal{P}\hat{\rho}=\hat{\rho}^{(B)}_{eq}\otimes \mathrm{Tr}_B[\hat{\rho}] $$

Where $\hat{\rho}$ is the density matrix, $\mathrm{Tr}_B$ is a partial trace over "bath" states and $\hat{\rho}^{(B)}_{eq}$ is an equilibrium density matrix in the bath subspace.

This is the only projection superoperator I've come across and I was wondering if they can always be written in a form similar to this, any information on projection superoperators would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to construct projection superoperators is to follow the direct analogy with the usual Hilbert space. Let $\mathscr H$ be the Hilbert space and $\mathscr L(\mathscr H)$ the space of linear operators on $\mathscr H$ equipped with the trace scalar product, $(A|B) = Tr(A^\dagger B)$. Then ${\mathcal P}:{\mathscr L}({\mathscr H}) \rightarrow {\mathscr L}({\mathscr H})$ is a projector provided ${\mathcal P} = {\mathcal P}^2$.

If we ask that in addition ${\mathcal P} = {\mathcal P}^\dagger$, then by the usual argument nonvanishing eigenvalues of ${\mathcal P}$ are all unit, and if $\lbrace \hat \alpha \rbrace_\alpha$, $(\hat\alpha|\hat\alpha') = Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\alpha') = \delta_{\alpha'\alpha}$ is its orthonormal eigenbasis in $\mathscr L(\mathscr H)$, we have 
$$
{\mathcal P} = \sum_\alpha{|\hat\alpha)(\hat\alpha|}\\
{\mathcal P}(\hat \chi) = \sum_\alpha{Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\chi) \hat\alpha}\\
{\mathcal P}^2(\hat \chi) = {\mathcal P}\left(\sum_\alpha{Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\chi) \hat\alpha}\right) = \sum_\alpha{Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\chi) {\mathcal P}(\hat\alpha)} =\\
= \sum_\alpha{Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\chi) \sum_\beta{Tr(\hat\beta^\dagger \alpha) \hat\beta}} = \sum_\alpha{Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\chi) \sum_\beta{\delta_{\alpha\beta} \hat\beta}} = {\mathcal P}(\hat \chi)
$$

But the thermal projector is not self-adjoint. It reads instead
$$
{\mathcal P}_{th} = |\hat\rho_{eq})(\hat I|\\
{\mathcal P}_{th}(\hat \chi) = \hat\rho_{eq} Tr(\hat\chi)
$$
or for a bipartite system AB, 
$$
{\mathcal P}^{(B)}_{th} \equiv {\mathcal I}^{(A)}\otimes{\mathcal P}^{(B)}_{th} = {\mathcal I}^{(A)}\otimes|\hat\rho^{(B)}_{eq})_B(\hat I^{(B)}|\\
{\mathcal P}^{(B)}_{th}(\hat\chi) = Tr_B(\hat\chi)\otimes\hat\rho^{(B)}_{eq} 
$$
Fortunately other non-selfadjoint superoperator projectors are not difficult to construct. For instance any
$$
{\mathcal P} = |\hat\eta)(\hat\xi|\;\;\;\text{with} \;\;Tr(\hat\xi^\dagger\hat\eta) = 1\\
{\mathcal P}(\hat\chi) = Tr(\hat\xi^\dagger\hat\chi) \hat\eta
$$
Or take $\lbrace \hat \alpha \rbrace_\alpha$ as a nonorthogonal basis, $(\hat\alpha|\hat\alpha') = Tr(\hat\alpha^\dagger \hat\alpha') \neq \delta_{\alpha'\alpha}$, and let $\lbrace \hat {\bar \alpha} \rbrace_\alpha$ be the biorthogonal dual, $(\hat{\bar\alpha}|\hat\alpha') = Tr(\hat{\bar\alpha}^\dagger \hat\alpha') = \delta_{\alpha'\alpha}$. Then for any subset $S$ of labels $\alpha$ we can define 
$$
{\mathcal P} = \sum_{\alpha\in S}{|\hat\alpha)(\hat{\bar\alpha}|}\\
{\mathcal P}(\hat \chi) = \sum_{\alpha\in S}{Tr(\hat{\bar\alpha}^\dagger \hat\chi) \hat\alpha}
$$
and verify that ${\mathcal P} = {\mathcal P}^2$.

Note that superoperator projectors may have features without analog for regular projectors $\hat P\in\mathscr L(\mathscr H)$. For instance there are superoperator projectors that map any self-adjoint operator into another self-adjoint operator, the thermal projector being a trivial example, in the sense that it maps any trace class operator into a self-adjoint operator.

However, here are the more familiar examples: Let $\hat P\in\mathscr L(\mathscr H)$, $\hat P^2 = \hat P$ be a regular projector on $\mathscr H$, and let $\hat Q = \hat I - \hat P$ be its complement. Then all of the following define superoperator projectors on $L(\mathscr H)$: 
$$
{\mathcal P}(\hat\chi) = \hat P \hat\chi,\;\;\;\tilde{\mathcal P}(\hat\chi) = \hat\chi\hat P \\
{\mathcal Q}(\hat\chi) = \hat Q \hat\chi,\;\;\;\tilde{\mathcal Q}(\hat\chi) = \hat\chi\hat Q \\
{\mathcal P}\tilde{\mathcal P}(\hat\chi) = \hat P\hat \chi\hat P,\;\;\;{\mathcal Q}\tilde{\mathcal Q}(\hat\chi) = \hat Q\hat \chi\hat Q\\
{\mathcal P}\tilde{\mathcal Q}(\hat\chi) = \hat P\hat \chi\hat Q,\;\;\;{\mathcal Q}\tilde{\mathcal P}(\hat\chi) = \hat Q\hat \chi\hat P
$$
and assorted combinations involving $\hat P^\dagger$, $\hat Q^\dagger$, etc. In particular, we can check that ${\mathcal P}^\dagger(\hat\chi) = \hat P^\dagger\hat\chi$ and that ${\mathcal P}^\dagger\tilde{\mathcal P}$ maps any self-adjoint operator into a self-adjoint operator, etc.

Comment: One should remember that density operators are elements of the trace class where the concept of orthogonality does not apply. Thus, if one wants to consider the problem in terms of the trace class topology the situation is somewhat different.

Comment: @Urgje Superoperators should be able to act on the full matrix space, not only on the space of trace class operators.  Otherwise, how would you define their action on part of a larger system?

Comment: Given a superoperator acting on elements of the trace class one obtains it on the class of bounded operators (with the sup norm) by duality.  What do you mean with full matrix space? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindblad_superoperator for a general setting.

Comment: @Urgje Your reference to the Lindblad generator suggests that what you have in mind is the convex set of positive definite operators whose trace class subset covers density matrices. Keep in mind though that the Heisenberg representation for a Lindblad generator, and with it the physics described, uses the entire ${\mathscr L}({\mathscr H})$ space.

Comment: @Urgje Regardless, superoperator projectors as a concept are completely independent of what happens on the set of trace class positive definite operators. Some map this set onto itself, see the last ${\mathcal P}^\dagger\tilde{\mathcal P}$ example in the answer, but most do not. If you are interested specifically in the former kind, that is another problem in itself.

Comment: Well, as I recall of work I did a long time ago, the specific topology is relevant, for instance in scattering problems and with ergodic limits. Superoperators or transformers, as they were called in the mathematical literature, are indeed mappings from classes of operators into themselves or other classes of operators. In case they contain operator multiplications with unbounded operators then their existence need to be investigated carefully. I was thinking of these aspects writing my remark.

Comment: @Urgje I know what you mean, on topology and unbounded operators, and I completely agree. But the Hilbert space structure itself for ${\mathcal L}({\mathcal H})$ is also most handy if used properly, including for a discussion of superoperator projectors.

Comment: Al right, we understand each other.  There is something in your answer that puzzles me. You introduce the inner product that defines the Schmidt class of operators. Is this intentionally? Obviously it is not defined for general bounded operators acting on $H$ including the unit operator. Unless $H$ is finite dimensional of course.

Comment: @Urgje The trace inner product is simply very convenient. True, it is first defined for trace class operators, not for all bounded operators, the Hilbert-Schmidt operators being the completion of the trace class in the corresponding trace (Hilbert-Schmidt) norm. This would pose serious limitations at first sight, but then we also have that the product of any bounded operator with a trace class operator is again trace class. With some care we can invoke this to extend the use of the trace inner product to most situations of interest involving bounded, but not trace class operators.

Comment: I agree it is convenient. However, in the past I was forced to stick to the trace class topology in order to treat certain limiting problems. Indeed the product of a trace class operator and a bounded one is again trace class. In fact the dual of the trace class with the trace norm topology is the space of bounded operators with the sup norm. Thus operators acting on the trace class can be ported to the bounded operators by duality. The Schmidt class, a Hilbert space, is its own dual, however. For the simple cases considered here there are indeed no problems.