# What is the general form of projection operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space

Usaully, a projection operator is expressed as the outer product of a state with ifself. But is this the most general form? And I am also confused with the relationship between Hermitian Operator and Projection Operator. It seems all projection operator all Hermitian. And all Hermitian operator can be expressed as sum of some projection operators. Are these two statements correct? Is there any exceptions?

Comment: A projection is any bounded operator that satisfies "p^*p=p". As a consequence, every projection is self-adjoint. By the spectral theorem, every bounded self-adjoint operator is a "linear combination" of projections that converges in norm (there is a spectral measure, i.e. a projection-valued measure $E$ carried by the spectrum $\sigma(A)$ of the self-adjoint operator $A$ such that $A=\int_{\sigma(A)}\lambda\text dE(\lambda)$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But it 's a little too abstract to me.  What is the physical meaning of self-adjoint? And what do you mean by "converges in norm"?

Comment: Roughly speaking, self adjointness is the essential property of observables. The norm-convergence bit is to be intended in the context of von Neumann algebras, where every element is a countable linear combination of projections that converges in the operator norm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any projection operator can be written as $P = \sum_{i=1}^n |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i |$, where the $\{ | \psi_i \rangle \}$ are orthonormal.  If $n$ (the "rank" of the projection) equals the dimension of the Hilbert space, then $P$ is the identity; if it's less, then $P$ is a nontrivial projection operator.  All projection operators are indeed Hermitian.  But your statement "And all Hermitian operator can be expressed as sum of some projection operators" is wrong: all Hermitian operators can be expressed as a *weighted* sum of projection operators $H = \sum_{i=1}^N \lambda_i |\psi_i \rangle \langle \psi_i |$, where the $\lambda_i$ are real numbers.  But $H$ is only a projection operator if the $\lambda_i$ are all 1 or 0.  (This is because 1 and 0 are the only complex numbers than square to themselves.)

Comment: That is actually not true. What you describe is an *orthogonal* projection. By definition, a projection is an operator which fulfils $P^2=P$ and need not be Hermitian. For instance the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}{} 1  & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ fulfils the projection properties but is not an orthogonal projection.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.@tparker @Martin I think it's clear to me now.

Comment: @Martin Good point, although I've never seen oblique projections actually come up in quantum mechanics.

Comment: sorry, i got it@tparker

Comment: @user129155 In practice, orthogonal projections (the ones I described in my answer) are so universal in quantum mechanics that if someone talks about a "projection" (in the context of QM) they probably mean "orthogonal projection" unless they specifically say otherwise.

Comment: @tparker: That's course true, especially since you are usually workingwith spectral projections of Hermitian operators, which are clearly orthogonal. Still, in order not to trip about it, it's good to know the whole story.

Comment: See this question for an example of non-orthogonal projection in quantum mechanics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240417/how-to-represent-a-liouville-projection-superoperator-in-hilbert-space